# Idiomatic way of implying "by a multiplicative factor"

Tags: idioms, mathematics, comparatives

I was told that saying

> A equals B within a factor C

is not correct. Is it true? My interlocutor, who is not a native anglophone, told me that "within" cannot be used in such a way, arguing that *"[...] A is not inside a factor C, is it?"*

Actually, I saw this idiomatic expression [here and there](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=within+a+factor), but I need a human confirmation.

Comment: In French, the closest correct translation would be "*A égale B à un facteur C près*".

Comment: "A is not inside a factor C, is it?" No, but there is some number *n* within (the range) 0 to C. And *n* x A = B (or A = *n* x B). Personally, I'd handle it differently. A differs from B by less than a factor of C (B is reference quantity). A and B differ by less than a factor of C (there isn't a preferred reference quantity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query can be interpreted more than one way, e.g., as a logical syllogism, as a statistical statement of conditional equality, and perhaps more. *Within a factor* can be read as 'as a function of C' or, rewriting the whole thing, 'Conditional on C, A equals B' or even 'In the presence of C, A equals B.' In all instances, C is acting as a moderator of the relationship between A and B and in the absence of that moderation, it is implied that A and B have no association and/or are independent.